# SearchListNode Error

Tags: c, list

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;

int search(ListNode *head, int value);
void printList(ListNode *head);

int main()
{
    ListNode *head = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int value = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->item = i;
    }
    printList(head);
    printf("Enter the value to search for: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    printf("Value of %d found in index %d",value,search(&head, value));
    return 0;
}

void printList(ListNode *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", head->item);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int search(ListNode *head, int value)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (head->item != value)
    {
        head = head->next;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I am trying to search a value inside a LinkedList and print out the index of the node when the value is found. But after my printlist, my program just shut down, I did not even reach to the part that require me to enter the value I want to search. Is there something wrong with my printList?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I edited your post to remove the *Solved* from the title. We don't use such convention here in SO. Accepting an answer is enough to let others know that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should check the return value of `scanf()` - it returns the number of items successfully matched and assigned. Only after checking the return value can you be sure that the values you use are valid.

The problem, however, is that you never terminate the list properly, that is, you never set the last node's `next` to NULL. Try to add this after the `while`:

```
temp->next = NULL;
```

Personally, though, I'd advice against doing so. In general, it is more elegant if the list itself is in a consistent state after each iteration of the loop. So, this is what I suggest instead:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Enter a integer: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
        /* Deal with invalid input... */
    }
    if (i == -1)
        break;
    ListNode *new_node;
    if ((new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node))) == NULL) {
        /* Deal with memory exhaustion */
    }
    new_node->item = i;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
        head = new_node;
    else
        temp->next = new_node;
    temp = new_node;
}
```

That makes `temp` work as a pointer to the previous node, so you might want to rename it to `prev`. Note the check for the return value of `scanf()` and `malloc()`, as well as the operand to `sizeof`: it is a good idea not to hardcode the type when using `sizeof` for maintenance reasons. Finally, notice, if you will, that there is now a single call to `malloc()`. This is conceptually easier to understand, since a new node is allocated in the same place in the code, regardless of `head` being valid or not.

Also, your `search()` function is broken. It assumes that if `value` is not the first node's value, then it is the second - not what you want. Also, you are not returning the *index* of the node, instead, you are returning the value itself. In fact, there's a situation where you return `NULL` (?!). I doubt that this compiles without warnings.

You need something like this instead:

```
int search(ListNode *head, int value)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (; head != NULL && head->item != value; head = head->next, res++)
        ; /* Intentionally left blank */
    if (head == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't put `temp->next` to `NULL` after this line `temp = temp->next;` in the list creation so it can be NULL or at any other value. When you iterate the list in `printList()` you reach this random value pointer and you have a segfault.